# Missing Image after taking photo with android camera intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-camera

I have developed an app that is taking picture using camera intent. Then after taking photo i will resize the photo and move it on application's directory. And also saving a thumbnail size photo. after all the process I will delete the photo in DCIM directory so the user won't be able to modify the photo.

Now my problem is some of the user reportedly that all the photos they took had gone missing. When checking all the applications directory, no photos was really saved and no photos in DCIM is saved. I did try to replicate the scenario but I can't recreate it.

Here is my code after launching the camera intent:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    String f = null;
     Bitmap bitmap = null;
     long fileSize = 0;
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST){

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){

            try {
                if (data!=null){

                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("PHOTO", MODE_PRIVATE); 
                    //String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);

                      f = prefs.getString("filename", fileName);//"No name defined" is the default value.
                      int  tvID = prefs.getInt("textView", tv.getId());
                        int  imgID = prefs.getInt("imageView", imageView.getId());

                    //Uri selectedImage = Uri.fromFile(new File(fullFileName)); 


                    tmpDir =  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" +
                            getResources().getString(R.string.tmpPhotoDirectory);
                    photoDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" +
                            getResources().getString(R.string.photoDirectory);
                    fullThumbnailName= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" +
                            getResources().getString(R.string.thumbnailDirectory);
                    fullBackupPath =
                                    getResources().getString(R.string.backupPhotoDirectory);


                    if (selectedImage!=null){
                        //ctx.getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);
                        if (ctx == null){
                            System.out.println("CTX is null");
                            ctx = BN38JEstateInspection.getContext();
                        }
                        ContentResolver cr = ctx.getContentResolver(); 
                        System.out.println("Selected Image:" + selectedImage.getPath());
                        Log.i("Result", f);

                        bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media 
                        .getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);
                        saveBitmapToExtCard(bitmap, f);



                        //scaled = ShrinkBitmap(getRealPathFromURI(ctx,selectedImage),  PIC_WIDTH, PIC_HEIGHT,bitmap);
                        fileSize = savePicture(tmpDir + "/" + f, bitmap, PIC_WIDTH, PIC_HEIGHT);
                        if (fileSize > 0){
                            //bitmap = ShrinkBitmap(getRealPathFromURI(ctx,selectedImage),  THUMB_PIC_WIDTH, THUMB_PIC_HEIGHT,bitmap);
                            savePicture(fullThumbnailName + "/" + f.replace("tmp_", ""), bitmap, THUMB_PIC_WIDTH, THUMB_PIC_HEIGHT);
                            tv = (TextView) findViewById(tvID);
                            tv.setText(f.replace(".tmp_", ""));
                            defaultPhoto = f.replace(".tmp_", "");
                             imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(imgID);
                            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fullThumbnailName + "/" + f.replace("tmp_", "")));
                            Toast.makeText(ctx, "Photo Saved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }else{
                            tv.setText(defaultPhoto);
                            fileName = defaultPhoto;
                            imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
                            Toast.makeText(ctx, "Error Saving Photo. Kindly retake photo.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                       deleteImageFromDCIM();
                        //System.out.println("Image Name:" + getLastImage());
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(ctx, "Null Error Saving Photo. Kindly retake photo.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(ctx, "Null Error Saving Photo. Kindly retake photo.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                tv.setText(defaultPhoto);
                fileName = defaultPhoto;
                imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
                Log.e("ERROR " +  TAG, "onActivityResult " + e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else{
            //super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            Toast.makeText(ctx, "Error Saving Photo. Kindly retake photo.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if (bitmap != null)
        {
            bitmap.recycle();
        }

    }
```

Is there anyone of you have same problem?

The phone they are using in note 1 upgraded to jellybean. Other user uses note 3 lollipop and didn't experience the problem.

Is this a jellybean problem or phone problem?

Thanks.

Comment: are you using multiple libraries ?

Comment: Nope. I'm only using the default of android. I am using multiple directory to save photos.

Comment: ohk sometime the problem is with phone below 5.0 version if it is something like that this link might help doesnt seems related answer with the proble but it works https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html#avoid